# Where did the featured MSO posts go?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, community-bulletin

Currently, there are 3 [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts here, on MSO. However, they aren't visible from both the main and meta sites:

> [image]

Where did they go?

Comment: They were missing when I saw your question on the MSO frontpage, but when I clicked through they were back again. Odd.

Comment: @F1Krazy looks like they're back now.

Comment: I'm getting a case of something like this right now. There are three featured posts on MSO, and I don't see any of them in the sidebar. instead I just see four hot meta posts :/